# Error compiling the test file generated from spring cloud contract groovy DSL

Tags: spring-cloud-contract

I am using spring cloud contract testing using Springboot 2.4.3, contract verifier 1.0.3 release. I created a groovy DSL contract for message based testing as below

package doc.messaging

Contract.make {
        description 'contract'

```
    label 'label2'
    input {
    messageFrom('generateDoc')
    messageBody([
            docId: 'D111'
    ])
}
outputMessage {
    sentTo('DocGenerated')
    body([
            "docId"     : value(consumer('D1111'), producer(regex('.*'))),
            "DocNumber" : value(consumer('123'),producer(regex('.*')))
    ])
}
```

}

it got failed and gives following error:

```
Error:(24, 89) java: method create in class org.springframework.cloud.contract.verifier.messaging.internal.ContractVerifierMessaging<M> cannot be applied to given types;   required: java.lang.Object,java.util.Map found: java.lang.String   reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
```

Please help.

Comment: Can you please post this somewhere or at least properly format the code? I can't read this properly.

Comment: It still looks bad - can you format the whole contract please? from what I see you label is in the description which is completely wrong. It would be best if you could upload your contract somewhere. Also please update your generated test.

Comment: uploaded files to https://gist.github.com/ramju/b19f562a5f7a954afd1cbf09b8597298.

Comment: Thank you so much for looking into this issue

Comment: can anyone provide advise on this issue? appreciate your great help

Comment: I think that this is a bug. Please file a bug in Spring Cloud Contract github project. As a workaround you can provide a section with headers cause form what I see it's missing in the create method - that's why the compiler is screaming that the code is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem my come from a wrong declaration inside here:

```
body([
        "docId"     : value(consumer('D1111'), producer(regex('.*'))),
        "DocNumber" : value(consumer('123'),producer(regex('.*')))
])
```

It should look like this:

```
body([
        docId     : value(consumer('D1111'), producer(regex('.*'))),
        DocNumber : value(consumer('123'),producer(regex('.*')))
])
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. Its not a problem with the output, its problem with messageFrom() payload.If I replace this input with input {
  triggeredBy('func()') 
 } it works. Its giving problem only when I receive something from the input with message payload.